# remove row with condition and duplicate value on multi column

Tags: text-processing, awk

i need to remove line with condition, column 2 only "eating" and combination values on column 3 and column 4 already occurred in a previous line

my sample data csv like this:

```
a,eating,apple,2
b,throwing,banana,1
c,eating,apple,3
d,eating,apple,1
e,eating,banana,2
f,throwing,apple,2
g,throwing,banana,2
h,throwing,banana,3
i,eating,apple,2
j,eating,apple,3
k,eating,banana,1
l,throwing,banana,2
m,throwing,banana,1
n,throwing,apple,1
o,eating,apple,3
p,eating,banana,2
q,throwing,apple,1
r,throwing,apple,2
s,eating,apple,1
```

the output should be like this

```
a,eating,apple,2
b,throwing,banana,1
c,eating,apple,3
d,eating,apple,1
e,eating,banana,2
f,throwing,apple,2
g,throwing,banana,2
h,throwing,banana,3
k,eating,banana,1
l,throwing,banana,2
m,throwing,banana,1
n,throwing,apple,1
q,throwing,apple,1
r,throwing,apple,2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the input data is "simple CSV", i.e. that there are no embedded commas or newlines in any fields, then we may use `awk` like so:

```bsh
$ awk -F, '$2 != "eating" || !seen[$3,$4]++' file
a,eating,apple,2
b,throwing,banana,1
c,eating,apple,3
d,eating,apple,1
e,eating,banana,2
f,throwing,apple,2
g,throwing,banana,2
h,throwing,banana,3
k,eating,banana,1
l,throwing,banana,2
m,throwing,banana,1
n,throwing,apple,1
q,throwing,apple,1
r,throwing,apple,2
```

This prints the current line if the 2nd comma-delimited field is not precisely the string `eating` or (if the 2nd field *is* `eating`) if the combination of the 3rd and 4th fields has not been seen before.

The logical expression

```c
$2 != "eating" || !seen[$3,$4]++
```

may be rewritten as

```c
!($2 == "eating" && seen[$3,$4]++)
```

(which is the way the conditions were specified in the question) depending on which way is easiest to understand.  The two expressions are equivalent.

This is a simple variation of the common idiomatic way to remove duplicated lines while preserving the original record order using `awk`:

```bsh
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: @ddrackochan Please note that this will only take reference values `$3,$4` IF `$2` is `eating`. A `trowing` will not add to the `seen` value! E.g. if the first line was `a,eating,apple,4`, line `i` would appear, despite line `f` having `apple,2` as reference values (but with `throwing`).

Comment: @FelixJN This is what I have written in the answer and what the user has specified in the question. If you want me to change anything, then specify more carefully the  behavior that you think is more correct, taking into account that I'm replicating the expected result.  See also the `f` and `r` lines and the `g` and `l` lines.

Comment: I am sure you know it! I was a bit unsure if the values `$3,$4` had to appear as seen in combination with `eating` or anywhere independent of `eating` - I can see both interpretations matching, hence wanted to point it out for future readers where one might fail here.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed with extended regex mode (-E)  we can solve this problem, by maintaining the tuple  (3rd,4th fields) belonging to eating in the 2nd field lines.
Then we compare with the pattern space
and take the appropriate action.

```
sed -E '
  /\n/{
    s///;s/\n+/\n/g
  h;d;}
  /^[^,]+,eating,/{
    s/[^,]+/&\n/4;T
    s/[^,]+/\n&/3;G
    /(\n.+\n).*\1/d
    h;s/\n//;s///;P
  x;D;}
' file
```